# Phonegap barcode scanner: couldn't make it run

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've tried to create a default Phonegap barcode scanner trough plugin basic installation, but it didn't work well. I don't know what's happening. Here is my code:

```
var app = {
  // Application Constructor
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  // Bind Event Listeners
  // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
  // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
  bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },
  // deviceready Event Handler
  // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
  // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  },
  // Update DOM on a Received Event
  receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    console.log('-');
    console.log(cordova);
    console.log('-');
    console.log(cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner);
    console.log('-');
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
          "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
          "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
          Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      },
      function (error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
    );
  }
};
```

It's basically the default Phonegap plugin panel. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the `cordova.plugin.barcodeScanner`. I've created the project trough  the Phonegap Windows tool and ran the `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar` command inside the folder. Please help me, I can't see any code example of this working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call getScanner() function onClick event in javascript [Read More Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

```
 function getScanner(){
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
    ); }
```

let me know if its not working..

Comment: nothing happens, i thing that this may be some missconfiguration of my project, http://www.filedropper.com/homemarket < i've uploaded my project , i built it using phonegap tool for windows and followed the instructions of the github tool to install it